# Simple loop hide rows until blank ""?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to have a simple loop that hides rows until it comes to a blank row in column B, starting a B9.

I do this in another macro for a different report except I delete the rows; no issues and multiple conditions. But this one right here.... my loop never moves to the next row and cell. It ends up locking up my Excel until  i have force close/restart Excel.

```
Range("B9").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Text = ""
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Loop
```

I've tried multiple variations. Admittedly, I'm still new to this. Still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move cells in a do loop. I would also write it avoiding select. I did not try this code but it should work. Cheers!

```
dim i as integer
dim xlWS as worksheet
set xlWS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

i= 9
do until xlWS.cells(i,2).value = ""
  xlWS.Rows(i).Hidden = True
  i = i + 1
Loop
```